# When using the default filesystem cache, is Rails writing every single SQL query to disk?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

Rails caches SQL queries by default, and uses the filesystem for caching by default. Does this mean that in a default config, it writes a cache for every single SQL read query to disk?

Seems like there would be more discussion about this online and concern for what must be a significant negative performance impact, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: In my limited knowledge, most of the production systems use a specialized cache store like `memcache` or `redis` for cachiing, eliminating the need to look into performance considerations. 
I am not entirely sure on this, but I think even the disk-based cache will give a performance improvement over no caching at all. Also, since it is just writing to the local system, the effect might not be that significant in the larger scheme of things. But rails docs do say to clear it periodically since it can get filled up.
Would be an interesting benchmark to run though.

Comment: According to the rails docs the [SQL caching](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#sql-caching) is in memory per action (which makes way more sense than disk caching given the extremely ephemeral nature) Where did you see that the cached is stored on the local disk? There are other forms of caching using [Cache Stores](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#cache-stores)  but these are not the way SQL cache is stored. *"Rails provides different stores for the cached data (apart from SQL and page caching)."*

Comment: Ohhhhh - all these years I didn't know that